# How do I use .get() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

e = Entry(main).pack()

main.configure(bg = "Black")

s = e.get()

main.mainloop()
```

but then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//agsb2/2014intake/kfullman14/My Documents/CICT/Programming U6/Python/Python Challenges/Tkinter test.py", line 9, in <module>
    s = e.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *


def button():
    s = e.get()
    label.config(text ='See? There is a difference.You entered %s.' %(s))

main = Tk()

e = Entry(main, bd=5, width=40)

main.configure(bg = "Black")
button = Button(main, text="Do Something", command=button)
label = Label(main, text="I am needed to show the difference.")

e.pack()
label.pack()
button.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

You did declare the variable but you never said how and when to use it. Hence, you did not see any change. In the example above you have a button that reads the Input and uses it to change a label.

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: In your explanation you ignored the part that was actually causing the error. In `e = Entry(main).pack()`, `e` is assigned the return value of `pack()` which is `None` and `None` has no `get()` attribute. By changing this to `e = Entry(main)` `e.pack()`, `e` now is an `Entry` object which does have a `get()` attribute.

Comment: The error was added later. Just happy to help.